# How do you customize marker picture and infowindow in gmaps4rails via a partial?

Tags: gmaps4rails

class VenuesController < ApplicationController

def index

```
@search = Venue.search(params[:search])
@venues = @search.all(:order => "name ASC")
@json = @search.all.to_gmaps4rails do |venue, marker|
```

marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "info", :locals => { :object => venue })
    marker.picture({
                  :picture => "images/#{name}.png",
                  :width   => 32,
                  :height  => 32
                 })

end

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @venues }
end
```

end

Comment: IN MY PARTIAL:_info.html.erb
<h2><%= venue.name %></h2>
<p><%= venue.price %></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partial doesn't work because it expects variable named `venue`.

In your controller, try to change your locals hash to `:locals => { :venue => venue }`:

```
marker.infowindow render_to_string(
  :partial => "info", 
  :locals => { 
    :venue => venue 
  }
) 
marker.picture({
  :picture => "images/#{name}.png", 
  :width => 32, 
  :height => 32 
})
```

For your marker picture, what is your error?

hth.